# nmap my localhost with host name and ip to get different result

Tags: nmap

The domain name `debian.debian` point to 127.0.0.1

```
$ ping debian.debian
PING debian.debian (127.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from debian.debian (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
64 bytes from debian.debian (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
```

Scan my localhost to get different result, why?

```
debian@debian:~$ sudo nmap  debian.debian
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-10-15 09:56 HKT
Nmap scan report for debian.debian (127.0.1.1)
Host is up (0.0000050s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds

debian@debian:~$ sudo nmap  127.0.0.1
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-10-15 09:56 HKT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000050s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
25/tcp   open  smtp
53/tcp   open  domain
80/tcp   open  http
631/tcp  open  ipp
5432/tcp open  postgresql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.11 seconds
```

I knew why `debian.debian` point to `127.0.1.1`.
Update:to add a question
Why http service is running on both 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.1.1?Why other services are running only on 127.0.0.1 instead of 127.0.1.1?

Comment: You say 127.0.0.1 but your output says 127.0.1.1 - that's not the same...

Comment: Following @StephenHarris comment, take a look at [this](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_hostname_resolution).

Comment: Are you asking how to find out what TCP ports are being listened to (for incoming connections) on your computer?  Try `sudo netstat -lnt`.